# An arrow between two points using tikz-cd

Tags: diagrams, arrows, tikz-arrows, commutative-diagrams

I drew the following diagram. I want to write "j" as a description in the midway (between K and P) but it doesn't apear. My code is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=huge,column sep=huge]
0 \arrow{r} & P \arrow{r}{\begin{bmatrix}
    p_{2} \\ p_{1}
    \end{bmatrix}
} 
& B \bigoplus A \arrow{r}{\begin{bmatrix}
    \alpha_{2} ~~ -\alpha_{1}
    \end{bmatrix}
} & C \\
& P^{\prime} \arrow[ur,"{\begin{bmatrix}
    {p^{\prime}}_{2} \\ {p^{\prime}}_{1}
\end{bmatrix}}" description] \arrow[r,dotted,"\exists!~u"'] & K 
\arrow[u,tail,"i ~ = ~ \begin{bmatrix}
    i_{B} \\ i_{A}
    \end{bmatrix}"'] 
\arrow[ul,"j" description, to path={-- 
([yshift=-2ex,xshift=-3ex]\tikztostart.south) -| 
([yshift=-2ex,xshift=-3ex]\tikztotarget.south) -- (\tikztotarget)}]
\end{tikzcd}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like this?

[image]

label to path is added as node on path:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=huge,column sep=huge]
0 \arrow{r} & P \arrow{r}{\begin{bmatrix}
    p_{2} \\ p_{1}
    \end{bmatrix}
}
& B \bigoplus A \arrow{r}{\begin{bmatrix}
    \alpha_{2} ~~ -\alpha_{1}
    \end{bmatrix}
} & C \\
& P^{\prime} \arrow[ur,"{\begin{bmatrix}
    {p^{\prime}}_{2} \\ {p^{\prime}}_{1}
\end{bmatrix}}" description] \arrow[r,dotted,"\exists!~u"'] & K
\arrow[u,tail,"i = \begin{bmatrix}
    i_{B} \\ i_{A}
    \end{bmatrix}"']
\arrow[to path={-- ([shift={(-2ex,-3ex)}]\tikztostart.south)
                -| ([shift={(-2ex,-3ex)}]\tikztotarget.south) node[pos=0.25,below,font=\footnotesize] {$j$} % <---
                -- (\tikztotarget)},
                ul]
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

**edit:**
from your comments one can guess that you looking for the following solution:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=22mm,column sep=huge]
0 \arrow{r} & P \arrow{r}{\begin{bmatrix}
    p_{2} \\ p_{1}
    \end{bmatrix}
}
& B \bigoplus A \arrow{r}{\begin{bmatrix}
    \alpha_{2} ~~ -\alpha_{1}
    \end{bmatrix}
} & C \\
& P' \arrow[ur,"{\begin{bmatrix}
    {p'}_{2} \\ {p'}_{1}
\end{bmatrix}}"  description, pos=0.25] \ar[r,dotted,"\exists!~u"'] & K
\arrow[u,tail,"i = \begin{bmatrix}
    i_{B} \\ i_{A}
    \end{bmatrix}"']
\arrow[ul,"j" description, pos=0.25]
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. It helped me a lot. How can I put "j" like the matrix between P' and B $\bigoplus$ A.

Comment: @math16, sorry, your sub question in above comment is not clear. do you like  that matrix is above arrow?

Comment: No. I want to write "j" in the midway and remove those parts of arrow that "j" is there.

Comment: than "j" will overwrite exiting label between P' and B $\bigoplus$ A. is this what you want? please add a sketch to your question and with it clarify what you like to obtain.

Comment: No. "j" is between K and P (in the midway, some parts of this arrow should be removed for "j").

Comment: Thanks. The second diagram is better. But, Why "description" doesn't work for "j" in the diagram I've provided in my question?

Comment: it works, however it is cowered by matrix. if you would ad "red" to this arrow, you would see it (better)